# Inline/Encoded SVGs as Lazyload placeholder

Tags: html, css, svg, responsive-design, lazy-loading

I'm using a lazyloader to replace `<img>` placeholder with the real image via Javascript.

Using a placeholder image on responsive sites (overriding `width` and `height` attributes via CSS) results in content jumps, when the real image with a different proportion has been loaded. So my plan was to insert simple inline SVG code with the dimensions of the final image.

1. Is this a good idea anyway?
2. How do I cope with `<img>` vs `<svg>` tag? (Needed as preloader placeholder)

[edit for clearer instruction – thanks @Robert Longson]

Comment: I think you need to ask a better, more specific question. Someone can currently answer this with either yes, or no, neither of which would be terribly helpful to you presumably.

Answer (score -1):

appelsiini.net lazyload

```
$("img.lazy").lazyload({
    effect      : "fadeIn",
    placeholder : "" // null or free
    //placeholder   : "loading.gif"
});

img.loading  {
    background: transparent url(../image/load.gif) no-repeat center center; 
}

<img class="lazy loading" ... />
```

Comment: please explain a little more detailed what is the solution.